# Form.Control <Options></Options>, how to select from a dropdown populated through JSON

Tags: reactjs, post, axios, dropdown

Form.Control , how to select from a dropdown populated through JSON from Axios Get request. Right now the entire JSON object gets selected when I am trying to send the post request even if I select 1 item from the dropdown [image]

```
enter code here<Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formGridServiceType">
                            <Form.Label>Service Type</Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control required 
                                //autoComplete="off"
                                as="select" 
                                name="serviceType.type"                                                                     
                                multiple={false}
                                value={this.state.serviceType.type}
                                onChange={this.serviceChange}
                                // onChange={this.change}
                                // inputRef={e1=> this.inputEl=el}
                                className={"bg-dark-text-white"} placeholder="Enter Service Type">
                                {this.state.serviceType.map((serviceType, key) => (                                        
                                        <option key={serviceType.id} value={serviceType.type}>{serviceType.type}</option>                                            
                                ))}
                            </Form.Control>
                        </Form.Group>
```

and my servicechange method is

```
serviceChange = event => {
    this.setState({

        [event.target.name]: [event.target.value]
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<Form.Control required 
                                //autoComplete="off"
                                as="select" 
                                //name="serviceType.type"   
                                name="serviceType"                                                                    
                                multiple={false}
                                //value={this.state.serviceType.type}
                                value={this.state.serviceType}
                                //value={this.serviceType}
                                onChange={this.serviceChange}
                                //onChange={this.change}
                                // inputRef={e1=> this.inputEl=el}
                                className={"bg-dark-text-white"} 
                                //placeholder="Enter Service Type"
                                >
                                {this.state.serviceType.map((serviceType, index) => (                                        
                                        <option key={index} value={serviceType.id}>{serviceType.type}</option>                                            
                                ))}
                            </Form.Control>
```

Got it resolved after trying multiple times with all possible option